# Error in the haskell program

Tags: haskell

I have made the following haskell program which will do some basic operations of load, read and increment. I am getting a type error. Can someone please tell why type error is there and how can i resolve it.

```
module ExampleProblem (Value,read',load,incr) where
newtype Value a = Value Int deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

read':: Value Int -> Int
read' (Value a) = a

load:: Int -> Value Int
load a = Value a

incr:: Value Int -> Value Int
incr (Value a) = Value (a+1)


main =  do
        (Value ab) <- (load 42)
        if (read'( Value ab) /= 42)
        then show "Failure to load"
        else do
             Value b <- incr( Value ab)
             Value c <- incr( Value b)
             if ((Value c) == Value 44)
             then show "Example finished"
             else show "error"
             return
```

The error i get is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Value t0'
In the pattern: Value ab
In a stmt of a 'do' expression: (Value ab) <- (load 42)
In the expression:
  do { (Value ab) <- (load 42);
       if (read' (Value ab) /= 42) then
           show "Failure to load"
       else
           do { Value b <- incr (Value ab);
                .... } }
```

And when i made a separate file in which i had written the main function i was getting the error of scope although i was importing the module ExampleProblem.

```
Not in scope: data constructor `Value'
```

Comment: 5 questions and no answers accepted. Work on that please.

Comment: Sorry i did not know about it.. Have made amends now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are confused about how to use do-notation. Do-notation is used for composing actions in a *monad*. In the case of `main`, that monad will be `IO` so I'll be sticking with `IO` to keep things simple.

There are three types of statements you can use in do-notation:

1. `x <- foo` binds the result of running the action `foo` to the pattern `x`. `foo` must have type `IO Something`, and `x` will then have the corresponding type `Something`.
2. `let x = foo` binds a value without anything special happening. This is the same as `=` at the top level, except that any preceding bindings are in scope.
3. `foo` runs an action of type `IO Something`. If it's the last statement in the do-block, this becomes the result of the block, otherwise the result is ignored.

The main problem in your code is that you're using `x <- foo` statements with things that aren't `IO` actions. That won't work. Instead, use the `let x = foo` form.

Secondly, `show` is also not an `IO` action. It's just a function that converts stuff to `String`. You probably meant to use `putStrLn` which will print a string to standard output.

Thirdly, `return` is not a statement like in C or Java. It's a function which, given a value, produces an action that does nothing and returns the value. It is often used as the last thing in a do-block when you want it to return a pure value. Here it is unnecessary.

And finally, if you want to run this code, your module must be called `Main` and it must export the `main` function. The easiest way of doing this is just to remove the `module ... where` line and the name will default to `Main`. You typically only want this line with the in modules in your project which don't contain `main`.

```
main =  do
    let Value ab = load 42
    if read' (Value ab) /= 42
      then putStrLn "Failure to load"
      else do
         let Value b = incr (Value ab)
         let Value c = incr (Value b)
         if Value c == Value 44
           then putStrLn "Example finished"
           else putStrLn "error"
```

This should work, but you're needlessly wrapping and unwrapping your values in the `Value` type. Perhaps you intended something like this:

```
main =  do
    let ab = load 42
    if read' ab /= 42
      then putStrLn "Failure to load"
      else do
         let b = incr ab
         let c = incr b
         if c == Value 44
           then putStrLn "Example finished"
           else putStrLn "error"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with your second question.

```
newtype Value a = Value Int deriving (Eq,Read,Show)
```

This actually creates *two* `Value`s:

- the `Value` in `newtype Value a` is a **type constructor**
- the `Value` in `Value Int` is a **data constructor** (usually just call it a constructor)

They are different things!

```
module ExampleProblem (Value,read',load,incr) where
```

Here `Value` means the type constructor. To export the data constructor as well, you need

```
module ExampleProblem (Value(Value),read',load,incr) where
```

---

Now, about your first question.

- `main` must have type `IO something`

You've set `main` to be a `do` block, so that means

- everything to the right of an `<-` must have type `IO somethingOrOther`

The line with the error message is

```
    (Value ab) <- (load 42)
```

`load 42` has type `Value Int`, clearly nothing to do with `IO`, so you get an error.

So how do you fix this?

- if a line of code in a `do` block is not an IO statement, it must be a let statement<sup>1</sup>

Other errors you need to fix:

- `return` doesn't do what it does in every other language.
  In particular, it always takes a value to return.
  We should have called it something else. Sorry about that.
  Imagine it's called `pure` instead. Anyway, you don't need it here.
- to print a `String` to the screen, you should use `putStrLn`, not `show`.
  Ghci prints the return value of expressions you give it, but this is a program in its own right,
  so you have to do the IO yourself.
- `then` and `else` need to be indented further than the `if` (I think this rule is changing, but I don't think it has yet)

So we end up with

```
main =  do
        let Value ab = load 42
        if read' (Value ab) /= 42
          then putStrLn "Failure to load"
          else do
               let Value b = incr (Value ab)
               let Value c = incr (Value b)
               if Value c == Value 44
                 then putStrLn "Example finished"
                 else putStrLn "error"
```

---

Footnotes:

1. Not strictly true: `do` blocks can be used for things other than IO. But you'll learn about that later.

Answer (score 2):

One additional remark: You should try to do as much work outside the main-IO thing as possible. In your case it's easy: You have a calculation which takes no argument and produces a String (which should be printed out). If you had different "outcomes", you could use e.g. `Either`, but here we are fine with just `String` as return type.

As hammar pointed out it makes not much sense to pattern match and reconstruct `Value` all the way, just use the values as they are, and use pattern matching only if you need to access the number inside.

The type Value doesn't need to be polymorphic if it always wraps just an `Int`, so I dropped the `a`. Else you have something called a "phantom type", which is possible and sometimes even useful, but definitely not here (of course if you want to be able to wrap *arbitrary* types, you can write `data Value a = Value a`).

So here is a version which does only the bare minimum in `IO`, and keeps everything else pure (and hence flexible, testable etc):

```
data Value = Value Int deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

read':: Value -> Int
read' (Value a) = a

load:: Int -> Value
load a = Value a

incr:: Value -> Value
incr (Value a) = Value (a+1)

main = putStrLn calc

calc :: String
calc = let ab = load 42
       in if read' ab /= 42 then "Failure to load" else increaseTwice ab

increaseTwice :: Value -> String 
increaseTwice v = let b = incr v
                      c = incr b
                  in if c == Value 44 then "Example finished" else "error"
```

I can't use Haskell here, so I hope this works...